# Where is the focus going?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

When an element on a page loses focus, the focus always goes somewhere else; the handler for the blur event receives an event object but I don't see anything in there that tells me where the focus is going.

How can I find that out?

Comment: Have you tried to bind a handler to the `focus` event?

Comment: Focus might go anywhere, including outside the document. Put a focus listener on the body, you should get a focus event just after the blur if the focus went to an element in the same document.

Comment: @Felix: binding a handler on the `focus` event is impossible since I don't know which element is getting the focus.  that is what I'm trying to discover!

Comment: @RobG: getting a focus event after I got the blur event doesn't help me.  I need to know where the focus is going at the time that the blur is issued because I need to make some decisions about it at that time.  specifically, my problem is that if a textbox is losing focus because it's going to a listbox of a certain class then I want to do something, if it's going anywhere else, I need to do something else

Comment: Well, events bubble up the DOM tree. But I tried it and for some reason it did not work...

Comment: @Felix, `focusout` bubbles but `blur` doesn't... I'm sure it's similar for `focus`... but as you can see from my other posts here, it wouldn't help me.  my problem is that the jQuery autocomplete really shouldn't send a `focusout` event to the textbox when the user is picking an item from the listbox because he's not really leaving the textbox... so I'm trying to figure out a way to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's at least a partial answer: you can hook the /mousedown/ event, which bubbles up and which occurs before focus actually changes.  if the user hits a tab instead of using the mouse, I don't know how it can be done!

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Focus_and_Selection

There's a section called 'Getting the currently focused element' which explains exactly how to achieve what you need, via the following code:

```
function init(){
  addEventListener("focus",setFocusedElement,true);
}

function setFocusedElement(){
  var focused = document.commandDispatcher.focusedElement;
  document.getElementById("focused").value = focused.tagName;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: CarlesAndres, thanks for the reply but hooking up to the `focus` event of any element does me no good.  my problem is I need to know _at the time_ of the loss of focus, where the focus will be going.  You see my issue is I'm using jQueryUI's autocomplete functionality which displays a listbox (a UL, actually) as the user types into a textbox.  if the user clicks on an item, a `blur` event is issued for the textbox and I need to know whether the textbox is losing focus because the user is picking something from the list, or because he's done with his entry and is moving anywhere else.